# How to pass fun.aggregate as argument to dcast.data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

TL;DR: how can I pass `fun.aggregate` into `dcast.data.table` when the call to `dcast.data.table` is done within a function (to which I pass `fun.aggregate`)?

I have a table like this:

```
library(data.table)
t <- data.table(id=rep(1:2, c(3,4)), k=c(rep(letters[1:3], 2), 'c'), v=1:7)
t
   id k v
1:  1 a 1
2:  1 b 2
3:  1 c 3
4:  2 a 4
5:  2 b 5
6:  2 c 6
7:  2 c 7  # note the duplicate (2, c)
```

I reshape to long format, retaining the last occurence of duplicates

```
dcast.data.table(t, id ~ k, value.var='v', fun.aggregate=last) # last is in data.table
   id a b c
1:  1 1 2 3
2:  2 4 5 7
```

However if I wrap my `dcast.data.table` call into a function:

```
f <- function (tbl, fun.aggregate) {
    dcast.data.table(tbl, id ~ k, value.var='v', fun.aggregate=fun.aggregate)
}
f(t, last)
Error in `[.data.table`(data, , eval(fun.aggregate), by = c(ff_)) : 
  could not find function "fun.aggregate"
```

It looks like the symbol `fun.aggregate` is being evaluated (`eval(fun.aggregate)`) and not found (since the function "fun.aggregate" does not exist).

**How should I pass my desired `fun.aggregate` in to `f`?**

(I'm sure it has something to do with `quote`, `substitute` etc but I struggle greatly with those functions and I typically just chain them together at random until something works).

---

Edit:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

...

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.3
```

Oops, I just realised that this bug is in 1.9.3 (dev version, which I upgraded to to avoid an unrelated bug) and **not** in 1.9.2 (current CRAN release version).

I would rather not downgrade to 1.9.2 (aforementioned bug I'm avoiding), so **in general is there a way to protect an argument to a function from the `eval()` call?**

Comment: works for me.. update your software

Comment: @rawr: sorry, forgot to include version information. I'm pretty up-to-date.

Comment: hm. idk what to tell you. only differences are that I'm on osx and running a [patched version](http://r.research.att.com/#nightly)

Comment: I downgraded to 1.9.2 also and the problem still un-persists.

Comment: In 1.9.3, aggregation was moved from C- to R-side to take advantage of recent GForce improvements in speed - [#523](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/523) and [README 1.9.2 new features point:6](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md). Reproducible in 1.9.3. Could you please file a bug [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md)? Thanks.

Comment: Suggest that this be closed as it's specific to data.table 1.9.3 and a bug (I had assumed this was a more general R/data.table question). Bug is [here, #713](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/713).

Comment: It's not off-topic, but it's too specific (ended up being a specific bug rather than a general question).

Comment: If you wish, you can delete the question. But if it's closed now, there'll be no way to update that it's fixed (when it's fixed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed in [commit 1303](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/aff5621d0ad62a074b627d30b8f7c29627ef0838) from [v 1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) - the current development version. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> `dcast.data.table` handles `fun.aggregate` argument properly when called from within a function that accepts `fun.aggregate` argument and passes to `dcast.data.table()`. Closes [#713](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/713). Thanks to mathematicalcoffee for reporting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24542976/559784) on SO.

---

Note that there was another small oversight in `dcast.data.table` that's been fixed now - [#715](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/715).

The issue is that `last` function does not produce a length-1 value for all input values - which is a requirement for `fun.aggregate`.

```
last(integer(0))
# [1] integer(0)
```

When `fill` argument is not set, this is the value that's used to fill missing combinations. This case was not caught before, but is now fixed.

Here's an example of the (correct) behaviour now:

```
tt <- t[1:5] # t is from your example
dcast.data.table(tt, id ~ k, fun.aggregate=last)
# Error in dcast.data.table(tt, id ~ k, fun.aggregate = last) : 
#   Aggregating function provided to argument 'fun.aggregate' should always return 
#   a length 1 vector, but returns 0-length value for fun.aggregate(integer(0)). 
#   This value will have to be used to fill missing combinations, if any, and 
#   therefore can not be of length 0. Either override by setting the 'fill' argument 
#   explicitly or modify your function to handle this case appropriately.

dcast.data.table(tt, id ~ k, fun.aggregate=last, fill=NA)
#    id a b  c
# 1:  1 1 2  3
# 2:  2 4 5 NA
```

Comment: wow, didn't expect such a fast turnaround (you probably have much more important things to do :)) thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe I'm seeing this bug again in v1.9.6. Same use case, same error. Happy to create a new SO post, but thought I'd start here.

Comment: Here's the [github bug report](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1369) - open at the time of writing.